# Bootstrap accordion won't collapse other elements when one is opened

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I try to make an accordion with normal accordion behaviour: there should only be one open element. I found a similar problem here: [Collapse plugin: Only show one panel at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444758/collapse-plugin-only-show-one-panel-at-a-time), but the solution doesn't fit for me, as I match `data-parent="#pricing-list-0` with `id="#pricing-list-0"` in the parent element.

Here is the code

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="pricing-list-0">
    <ul class="list-group">

        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#pricing-list-0" href="#collapse0-0" class="" aria-expanded="true">
                            Artful &amp; responsive website, ...
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse0-0" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
              <div class="panel-body">You give us the freedom ...</div>
            </div>                            
        </li>
[...]
```

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/YVVbev

Why is it not closing, though `data-parent="#pricing-list-0"` and `id="pricing-list-0"` are matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4 update**

Accordion behavior works by using `data-parent` on the collapsible (.collapse) element.

**Bootstrap 3**

As you can see in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19425165/bootstrap-3-accordion-button-toggle-data-parent-not-working/19426220#19426220), 2 conditions must be met for the "accordion" behavior to work..

- `.panel` must be a child of the element used as `data-parent=`
- each accordion section (`data-toggle=`) must be a child the `.panel`

But, you're codepen is using Bootstrap 4, and there is no longer a `panel` class. Now the `card` class must be a child of the parent, so it would be..

```
<div class="panel-group" id="pricing-list-0">
     <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item card">
       ...
     </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/YGff3ecNvF

Comment: I didn't realize that CodePen uses Bootstrap 4 already. My project still has 3, so I have to think about migrating ... It looks like, what I want to do is not possible with 3 (combining list-group with the accordion)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you should add a

```
data-target="#collapse0-0"
```

To the a element

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. It jumps to the element, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had omitted the `#` at the beginning of the `data-target`element.